# ¿Cómo separar un query por fecha en columnas?

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta y me piden que la separe por fechas, en columnas:

Ejemplo

```
ENERO -> INFORMACIÓN
FEBRERO -> INFORMACIÓN
ETC.
```

Sólo que los tengo en un Select y sólo puedo regresar un dato por renglón.

```
select T1.Item_No,T1.Description,T1.Min_Quantity,T1.Max_Quantity,

ISNULL((SELECT sum(T3.Quantity) FROM Purchasing_v_Receipt_e T3 
WHERE T1.Item_Key = T3.Item_Key AND T3.Receive_Date BETWEEN '9/01/2019' AND '9/23/2019'),0) AS 'Entrada',

ISNULL((SELECT SUM(T4.Quantity) FROM Purchasing_v_Item_Usage_e T4 
WHERE T1.Item_Key = T4.Item_Key AND T4.Transaction_Type_Key = 3 AND T4.Usage_Date BETWEEN '9/01/2019' AND '9/23/2019'),0) AS 'Salida',

ISNULL((SELECT SUM(T5.Quantity) FROM Purchasing_v_Item_Location T5 
WHERE T1.Item_Key = T5.Item_Key ),0) AS 'Inventario Actual'

FROM Purchasing_v_Item T1
WHERE Item_No LIKE '%RPROD000%'
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor, evita usar mayúsculas sostenidas, pues en estos espacios, eso equivale a llegar a gritar y estamos seguros que esa no es la idea :)

Comment: Adicional a esto, en qué motor de BD estás trabajando? Procura añadir la etiqueta correspondiente cuando preguntes.